# CSS on hover change background colour and text colour as well

Tags: html, css

i want that when i move my mouse on menu. it will change background colour as well as it will change text colour.
but my CSS only change background colour, it will not change text colour.
need help please.

```
a:hover
{
    color: #231f20;     //for text new colour (not worked)
    background-color: #ffffff;     //for background new colour (it worked)
}
```

Comment: give exact target eg `parent` `child:hover`

Comment: thank you Fernandes. but i am new can you give me any example how to use parent and chiled: hover?

Comment: check the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/kn0LhLdv/) you will understand better

Comment: @FarrukhJaved Check here works: http://fiddle.jshell.net/0zmg9ja8/. will you post your whole code?

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand what you mean, the only reason why I don't think it worked was the way you tried to comment out the code, you were using `//` instead of `/*`.

Here's what I replaced it with:

```css
a:hover
{
    color: #231f20;     /*for text new colour (not worked)*/
    background-color: #088a68;     /*for background new colour (it worked)*/
}
```

```html
<a href="...">Small Example</a>
<br>
<a href="..." style="font-size: 50px">Big Example</a>
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/yn16bxsv/

Hope this helped

Comment: no i did comment for my query, i did not comment it in my code.

Comment: It should work, do you have a live example of what you are doing?

Comment: @ m brum
this is what i write in my css.
a:hover
{
    color: #231f20;
    background-color: #ffffff;

}

Comment: It does work, I updated the Fiddle. (https://jsfiddle.net/yn16bxsv/1/)

I'm assuming the background colour for your page is white, therefore if you set the background colour to white, you do not notice the difference.

As you can see, with a black background it does work